# Is there an R function like fill for filling NA's with characters as const

Tags: r, data.table, na, fill

I have a data.table as such:

```
missings_table = data.table( name = c("Jim","Paul",NA,"Sam"),
                         midterm = c(0,15,13,12),
                         final = c(0,NA,16,13));missings_table
```

What i want to do is similar to

```
nafill(missings_table$final,type = "const", fill = 0)
```

But if i try

```
nafill(missings_table$name,type = "const", fill = "name")
```

I get

```
'x' argument must be numeric type, or list/data.table of numeric types
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The manual page for `nafill` says "Only double and integer data types are currently supported."

Comment: When you use `fill="name"`, are you intending the replaced data to be the constant string `"name"`, or are you hoping that the replacement value is derived somehow from something in the `name` column?

Comment: @r2evans a constant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `nafill()` function currently does not support character data types.

So, here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach for replacing NAs in a character column by a constant value:

```
missings_table[is.na(name), name := "name"]
```

> ```
>    name midterm final
> 1:  Jim       0     0
> 2: Paul      15    NA
> 3: name      13    16
> 4:  Sam      12    13
> ```

Comment: There is PR which adds this functionality to nafill

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of your fill is constant, you could use `tidyr::replace_na`

```
tidyr::replace_na(missings_table, list(name='name', final = 0))
   name midterm final
1:  Jim       0     0
2: Paul      15     0
3: name      13    16
4:  Sam      12    13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base function is.na() works well for this and is the easiest solution.

```
missings_table$name[is.na(missings_table$name)] <- "name"
```